# how to use a variable as part of inserting a formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

this code works

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[2019 Comm Tables.xlsx]table-ZZ'!R5C8"
```

I want to replace the hardcoded ZZ (part of sheet name) with a value from a variable

I have

```
Dim avar as string
avar ="AA"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='""[2019 Comm Tables.xlsx]table-"" & avar &  "" '!R5C8"""
```

this generates

> 'object defined error'

Any help on sorting out my coding errors would be gratefully received

Comment: Why all the extra quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to double up the double quotes, unless you have double quotes at the beginning of the string you're quoting.

```
   Dim avar As String
    avar = "AA"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[2019 Comm Tables.xlsx]table-" & avar & "'!R5C8"
```

Also, you had one space too many before the closing single quote.

Details matter.

Comment: ++ yup details matter :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[2019 Comm Tables.xlsx]table-" & avar & "'!R5C8"
```

Comment: All replies received thanks and problem resolved, I appreciate the time taken by you all.